# Edit Joomla Articles with Emacs

Tags: sql

Editing Joomla articles in the web interface is the most pain the world.

The articles in Joomla are stored in a mysql database.

I'd like to figure out how I can connect a buffer to a "value" in mysql database, which contains the html code, so that I can edit the html in Emacs.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Please specify what you have tried, what you saw, and what you expected instead. Try to provide a step-by-step recipe that starts from `emacs -Q` (no init file).